# Cookie base authentication not working when i run my next app on ssl

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js, axios

I have a nx next app that is using http-proxy to run my next app on ssl `http` The reason I did this is becuase the the cookie base authentication headers block the cookie from being send.But the cookies are not being sent to the backend for authentication.

HttpProxy.js:

```
const https = require('https');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const fs = require('fs');

const proxyTarget = {
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4200,
  },
  secure: false,
};
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  ...proxyTarget,
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.crt'),
  },
  proxyTable: {
    changeOrigin: true,
    autoRewrite: true,
    cookieDomainRewrite: {
      '*': 'localhost',
    },
  },
});

// Create the HTTPS server
try {
  const server = https.createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.crt'),
    },
    (req, res) => {
      console.log(
        'Proxy HTTPS request at %s%s',
        req.url.slice(0, 50),
        req.url.length > 50 ? '...' : '',
      );
      proxy.web(req, res);
    },
  );

  // Start listening on port 443 (HTTPS default)
  server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Proxy server running on port https://localhost:3000');
  });

  // Error handling for the proxy server
  proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
    console.error('Proxy server error:', err);
    res.writeHead(500, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    });
    res.end('Please run web app by running "npm run start" or "yarn start" ');
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error creating HTTPS server:', error);
}
```

Axios instance:

```
export const createHttp = (baseURL: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const http = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true,
    ...config
  });
  http.defaults.headers['x-device-type'] = 'browser';

  return http;
};
```

request headers:

[image]

I have tried changing the configuration of the proxy server but still it does not works and I have tried give `withCredentials: true` to all the authenticated routes but still I don't see any solution for this